# Не запускается приложение на другом компьютере

Tags: c#, отладка, windows

Думаю, что-то с зависимостями, но все dll, которые были в папке скомпилированной программы, я перекинул на другой компьютер, но приложение все равно не запускается. .Net framework, конечно, обновлял. Есть ли способ проверить, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если .Net Framework на компах совпадает и все dll вы скопировали, я предполагаю следующее:

1. Возможно, программа ожидает в GAC какую-то особую dll.
2. Возможно, программа написана с хардкодной привязкой на определённую структуру каталогов или файлов (к примеру, выполнение жёстко завязано на наличие какой-нибудь папки по определённому пути).

В обоих случаях решение возможно при наличии доступа к исходникам (найти зависимость в GAC и добавить недостающую библиотеку или узнать о "волшебной папке").

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, вам нужно собрать свой проект со всеми зависимостями в один пакет (исполняемый файл, если угодно). Делается это с помощью **ILMerge**. Процесс довольно несложный, как правило, ограничивающийся использованием стандартного BAT-скрипта от Microsoft. Подробнее **[вот здесь](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CC0QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhabrahabr.ru%2Fpost%2F126089%2F&ei=a7cNVZzGPKvGygOnnYL4BA&usg=AFQjCNEsM-2X8u4mh4_z8TopuNPVFquj1g&sig2=vHSr2Z5ssnxQJAOIRlV2iQ&bvm=bv.88528373,d.bGQ&cad=rjt)**.

Comment: Делаю все, как по инструкции по ссылке, но вылезает ошибка с кодом 1. И не понятно, как от нее избавиться.